# Tabulator Date Sorter not working correctly

Tags: javascript, c#, sorting, asp.net-core, tabulator

I am using `tabulator 5.3.4`, I have column that contains several DOB in MM/DD/YYYY format. When i click on sort icon, it only sort by months. Can anybody please help me with custom sort method that can sort the data correctly.
This is m column in tabulator:

```
{ title: "DOB", field: "RecentDOS", width: 80 }
```

[image: This is the sample data for you reference]

I have tried using `sorter` but that is not working due to some version mismatch, I guess.
Please help with any custom sorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I included `Moment.js` library and applied following code changes. It started working.

```
{title: "DOB", field: "RecentDOS", width: 80 sorter:"date", sorterParams:{
    format:"MM/dd/yyyy",
    alignEmptyValues:"top",
}}
```

For more Info: [click here](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/sort#sorter-date) to open tabulator documentation.